# phpMailer send a smtp email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send an email using phpMailer.

I have downloaded and put the files in "path2".

The php program has 3 inputs: $email, $subject and $body.

Here is the error code when ran:

```
2014-06-24 15:48:18 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once("..\path2\class.phpmailer.php");
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Eastern');
    include("..\path2\class.smtp.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; 
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = True;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "SSL";
    $mail->Host = "smtp.live.com";      
    $mail->Port = 465;                  
    $mail->Username   = "self@live.com";
    $mail->Password   = "pass1"; 
    $mail->From="self@live.com";
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->Body=$body;
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You can try using telnet command from your server to see if it is a network error or error in your php code.

Comment: specifics on the telnet cmd?

Comment: What do you mean by specifics?

Comment: He's asking for the command.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet isn't very useful for testing encrypted connections - openssl is better. Try this on your server:

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect smtp.live.com:465
```

That's currently not connecting for me from multiple countries, so perhaps Microsoft finally heeded the deprecation of SSL on port 465 back in 1998... Try this instead:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.live.com:587
```

That's working well for me, so I suggest you make these changes to your code:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port = 587;
```